# Remove the month and year from a WordPress Date?

Tags: functions, date

So, I am wondering if there is a way that I can make this:

```
February 28th, 2020
```

Just output NO month and NO year so just 28th (i.e. just the date)

What approach would you take?

I am applying this to a WordPress plugin called Pods.

The plugin allows for Custom Fields to be printed like this:

```
{@date}
```

And I know that you can run a PHP command from the functions file like this:

```
{@date,remove_month}
```

But figuring how to do that is tricky...any pointers?

Comment: I'd guess if it accepts anything it'd be a [PHP date format string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php): I guess you want `jS`. But how the plugin works / how you do this will be specific to the plugin, so you'd have to ask them or read the code to figure it out yourself.

Comment: If the date is just a date in a string, then you don't need WordPress stuff to figure out the answer, it can be done entirely using raw PHP from php.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll need to write your OWN function that will take the post_date and return it reformatted to the style you’re looking for.

```
function my_date($input_date) {
   return date("S", strtotime($input_date));
}
```

And then you would call it within your Pods Template like

```
{@post_date, my_date}
```

All rights goes to Jim True. More infomations : https://pods.io/forums/topic/date-formatting-using-magic-tags/

Comment: Thank you VERY much FloJDM